# No volume group in lvm2 disk? Want to mount a logical partition

Tags: lvm, cryptsetup

How am I supposed to mount a logical volume from a decrypted drive, when the `VG` column is blank? The last time I could do it, (`ubuntu-vg` was showing), but now it has a blank name?

```
root@debian:/home/adam# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb5 crypthome
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdb5: 
root@debian:/home/adam# mount /dev/mapper/crypthome /mnt/crypthome
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
root@debian:/home/adam# pvs
  PV                    VG Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  
  /dev/mapper/crypthome    lvm2 ---  232.41g 232.41g
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the default automatic volume group metadata backup in `/etc/lvm/archive/`, then you can use [this guide](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/recovermetadata.html) to restore the damaged metadata in the PV. Then you should be able to see the `lvs` and mount them, if they are intact.