# Physical Volume got created with "blank" volume group name on Ubuntu 18.04(VM)

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I have an issue similar to [No volume group in lvm2 disk? Want to mount a logical partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385806/no-volume-group-in-lvm2-disk-want-to-mount-a-logical-partition)

I am trying to create a new physical volume to which I am later going to add unallocated space usng lvm2.

Steps for reproduce:
1. Created Physical volume using pvcreate:-
`$pvcreate /dev/sda2`
2. Trying to list it using `lvmdiskscan`, it shows LVM Physical volume correctly.
     But When tried to check 'volume group' for the same, its empty:-

```
    $sudo lvmdiskscan

          /dev/loop0  [     <14.75 MiB] 
          /dev/loop1  [     <14.75 MiB] 
          /dev/sda1   [     <20.00 GiB] 
          /dev/loop2  [    <140.67 MiB] 
          /dev/sda2   [      20.00 GiB] LVM physical volume
          /dev/loop3  [      14.50 MiB] 
          /dev/loop4  [      54.64 MiB] 
          /dev/loop5  [      <3.65 MiB] 
          /dev/loop6  [      <2.25 MiB] 
          /dev/loop7  [     <89.09 MiB] 
          /dev/loop9  [     160.15 MiB] 
          /dev/loop10 [    <156.68 MiB] 
          /dev/loop11 [      44.88 MiB] 
          /dev/loop12 [     <44.18 MiB] 
          /dev/loop13 [      89.10 MiB] 
          /dev/loop14 [      54.64 MiB] 
          /dev/loop15 [      <4.20 MiB] 
          /dev/loop16 [      <3.65 MiB] 
          /dev/loop17 [    <140.67 MiB] 
          0 disks
          18 partitions
          0 LVM physical volume whole disks
          1 LVM physical volume  
    $sudo pvs
      PV         VG Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree  
      /dev/sda2     lvm2 ---  20.00g 20.00g
```

Since this volume group is 'blank', I'm not able to extend it.
Further, since its blank, absolutely no output is shown for vgdisplay and vgs commands

Please help!! I' m stuck in extending VM's disk size.
NOTE: I do not have any directory named 'archive' at `/etc/lvm/` location!!

Comment: WHat is the result of `vgs`?

Comment: The result of `pvs` mean this PV do not belong to any VG. What is the big idea?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You seem to run out of space on sda1 and you want to extend it using sda2, correct? But it seems as only sda2 is a (new) physical volume. If sda1 is not part of a volume group you won't be able to extend it. What you could try (not tested, so create a backup first before changing anything!) is to create a new vg on sda2, move all data there, test if that works (especially bootloader). If all is good recreate a blank sda1, make it a pv and then extend your volume group. If this is not what you're asking please rephrase and clarify.

Comment: @eblock My main intention is to extend disk space on my VM for ubuntu 18.04.  
From VMware settings, I have already expanded disk space to additional 20 GB.
In order to actually increase the logical volume, I am trying to use lvm2.    
Using lvm2, I am trying to extend the existing root partition '/dev/sda1'.  
I have then created new partition 'sda2', from which disk size can be taken from when extending the logical volume later. Now, after rebooting I created new physical volume. At this step, I see no volume group for this new volume. Hence, vgdisplay and vgs doesn't give any output!!

Comment: But it seems as if the first disk was *NOT* using lvm. Another way to extend disk space would be to delete sda2 and instead extend sda1 to use the additional space (again, make sure you know what you're doing and have a backup!), one tool would be `fdisk`.

Comment: @eblock, I am fine with any approach. But please guide me on the easy steps to extend existing root partition ..since I have never done it on linux :(

Comment: This should cover it:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime

Comment: @eblock Thanks for sharing the thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104024/discussion-between-manasikolhe9-and-eblock).